Prevent horizontal scroll reset when updating vue-ag-grid columnDefs
I'm trying to update vue-ag-grid's columnDefs with new values using the updateGridOptions method. However, this action resets the horizontal scroll back to the starting position, which leads to a poor user experience.
Here's the code snippet I'm using:
agGridRefs.value[`agGrid${index}`].api.updateGridOptions({ columnDefs: [rowToUpdate] })

How can I update the columnDefs without resetting the horizontal scroll position?
Update:
      <div class="grid-row" v-for="(columnDefs, index) in filteredColumnDefsList" :key="index">
            <ag-grid-vue
             :ref="`${gridUUID}_${index}`"
              :columnDefs="columnDefs"
              @grid-ready="onGridReady($event)"
              @columnMoved="handleColumnMoved($event, index)"
              :width="props.projectWidth"
            >
            </ag-grid-vue>
          </div>
function handleColumnMoved($event, index){
  const columnDef = anotherFunction(...params)
    agGridRefs.value[`${gridUUID.value}_${index}`].api.addEventListener('modelUpdated', () => {
      const columnsWithHeaderComponent = getColumnsWithHeaderComponent(
        agGridRefs.value[`${gridUUID.value}_${index}`].api.getColumnDefs()
      )
      agGridRefs.value[`${gridUUID.value}_${index}`].api.ensureColumnVisible(
        columnsWithHeaderComponent,
        'middle'
      )
    })
    agGridRefs.value[`${gridUUID.value}_${index}`].api.updateGridOptions({
      columnDefs: [columnDef]
    })
    columnDefsList.value[index] = columnDef
}


Are you able to reproduce the problem you're seeing on this demo: https://ag-grid.com/vue-data-grid/column-updating-definitions/? In my experience updating the column definitions does not explicitly reset the horizontal scroll position. Perhaps there's something else going on that's doing it.

@IanRobinson It did reset the horizontal scroll position.

Maybe try this one specifically: https://ag-grid.com/examples/column-updating-definitions/matching-columns/modules/vue3/ - if you resize your browser to get a horizontal scrollbar, set the scroll position and then add the additional columns, your scrollbar does adjust, but doesn't reset to the start. It keeps the data you're looking at in view. Maybe that begs the question: how different are your column definitions when you're updating? If you're moving them around or removing columns, the grid may not be able to keep its state?

How do I set the scroll position, ensureColumnVisible ?,

I will update the question with more information

@IanRobinson can u see any issues ?

does the modelUpdated event fire consistently after you call updateGridOptions? If so, the other potential issue I see is that ensureColumnVisible should take in the name of a single column for the first paramter, it appears that you may be passing in an array or a list.
